# Помогите с кодом Вроде бы простое задание, но не выходит сделать Коллбэк функция

Tags: javascript

Напишите две функции
`letMeSeeYourName(callback)` - спрашивает имя пользователя
через `prompt` и вызывает `callback` функцию
`greet(name)` - коллбек принимающий имя и логирующий в консоль строку `"Привет <name>"`
Реализуй проверку, что `prompt` не пустой

---

```
function greet(name) {
  console.log(`Hi, ${name}`);
}

function letMeSeeYourName(name, callback) {
  let userInput;

  while ((userInput = prompt("What is your name?", ""))) {
    if (userInput === "" || userInput === null) {
      alert("Say your name");
      continue;
    }
  }
  callback(name);
}

letMeSeeYourName(name, greet);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В `letMeSeeYourName` надо передавать только callBack функцию.
В цикле `while` надо просто проверять переменную `userInput`.
Для проверки, что `userInput` пустой, достаточно поставить значение в `if`, для отрицания используем !

```js
  function greet(name) {
    console.log(`Hi, ${name}`);
  }

  function letMeSeeYourName(callback) {
    let userInput;

    while (!userInput) {
      userInput = prompt("What is your name?", "")
      if (!userInput) {
        alert("Say your name");
      }
    }
    callback(userInput);
  }

  letMeSeeYourName(greet);
```

Comment: Спасибо!!! Все работает

Comment: зачем `continue`?

Comment: @Grundy В целом не за чем. Убрал.